Dynamically add property with type to interface
I have this interface
interface Base {
    common: {
        foo: string,
    }
}

interface ExtendedOne extends Base {
    count: number,
}

interface ExtendedTwo extends Base {
    origin: string,
}

Now, what I want is via the interface definition of ExtendedOne and ExtendedTwo add another property plus type to the common prop coming from Base.
So lets say (pseudocode)
interface ExtendedOne extends Base {
    count: number,
    common: {
        ...Base,
        anotherProp: boolean,
    }
}

interface ExtendedTwo extends Base {
    origin: string,
    common: {
        ...Base,
        anotherProp: number,
    }
}

The prop added will always have the same name (here anotherProp), but the type will be different.
If needed, the interface can be changed to a type.

You can use & operator in Typescript to combine types.
interface Base {
    common: {
        foo: string
    };
}

interface ExtendedOne extends Base {
    count: number
    common: Base["common"] & { anotherProp: boolean }
}

interface ExtendedTwo extends Base {
    origin: string
    common: Base["common"] & { anotherProp: number }
}

TypeScript has some great utility types too. For examples, check Omit and Pick that allow you to selectively create a new type by omitting or picking properties from another type.
